# How do you add text in a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

I have absolutely no idea how to add text to a batch file. I created a secret file that Shuts down your computer and I really want to know how to add text once you double-click on it!!!! HELP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. it will open new cmd window with text you want.

```
START CMD /C "ECHO Your message && PAUSE"
```

and if you want a pop up window you can use

```
mshta javascript:alert("Your message!!");close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ECHO. Also, put the quotes around the entire file path if it contains spaces.

One other other note, use > to overwrite a file if it exists or create if it does not exist. Use >> to append to an existing file or create if it does not exist.

Overwrite the file with a blank line:

```
ECHO.>"C:\My folder\Myfile.log"
```

Append a blank line to a file:

```
ECHO.>>"C:\My folder\Myfile.log"
```

Append text to a file:

```
ECHO Some text>>"C:\My folder\Myfile.log"
```

Append a variable to a file:

```
ECHO %MY_VARIABLE%>>"C:\My folder\Myfile.log"
```